# Can "be in service" be used to mean the opposite of "be on leave"?

Tags: word-request, word-meaning, idioms, expressions

I have checked various dictionaries and also googled the phrase, but I remain unsure as to whether or not "be in service" can be used as the opposite of "be on leave", so now I'm asking you lot instead :)

That is, would the following be acceptable:

> They may get compensation, provided that they were in service on the day in question

> I will be back in service on 1 May

Somehow I get the impression that this phrase is mostly used about public transport and the like, or, alternatively, about someone in the military? If my suspicion is correct, then what could I use instead? I realise I could simply use "work", but strictly speaking, you could be working even if you're officially on leave, so I need something that means 'officially not on leave'.

Comment: Do you want British or American answers? (Or answers for some other English variety)

Comment: @ThePhoton I guess I'm always interested to hear from both sides :)

Answer (score 2):

**in service** means that a *thing* -not a person- is working (functioning). See the second definition in The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/service?q=in%20service).

When used about a person, it has two possible meanings:

- that the person is on the payroll of an organization. One example of this is a [death in service](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/death-in-service) benefit, which is paid whether or not they were actually at work on the day that they died.
- that the person is employed as a domestic servant: this meaning appears near the end of this [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/service?q=in%20service) page.

Comment: In the UK Civil Service, 'in service' can mean 'currently employed'. If I die while I am in service, my wife gets a lump sum of 2.5 times my annual salary as a 'death in service' payment. Being in service and 'not in service' do not, in this sense, mean the same as 'on leave' and 'not on leave' respectively.

Comment: Thank you JavaLatte – I found those entries when I checked that dictionary, but I was unsure whether they actually excluded the possibility that it could **also** mean 'not on leave'. Either way, do you have a suggestion as to what I could use instead?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you! So that's yet another meaning... Do you have any idea what I could use instead of "be in service" to mean 'not on leave'?

Comment: @Mooshi - when I go on leave I set an automatic reply on my work email account saying e.g. 'I shall be back from leave on Monday March 7th, 2022'. A suitable 'opposite' to 'on leave' might be 'at work'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right, so you look at it from the opposite perspective (which would obviously work in my examples too). So, am I right to assume then that there isn't an expression in English for the exact meaning I'm after?

Comment: @Mooshi - Well, 'at work' is what I suggested above.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Hm, wouldn't that focus rather strongly on your being in the workplace, rather than on your not having a day off though? Also, another question that this raises: is there a difference (legal or other) between being on leave and having a day off? I guess you could say you have Saturdays and Sundays off, but you wouldn't say you're on leave these days, right?

Comment: @Mooshi - if I have a day off, I am on leave ('leave of absence'') for that day. No difference from three days, a week, or a month. I have 31.5 days each year (30 regular days, one day for the Queen's birthday, and a half day for Maundy Thursday). Also eight Bank Holidays. 'At work' can mean in attendance in the workplace (i.e. not working from home, travelling on office business, etc), or 'not on leave'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I really can't thank you enough for all your patient answers! I think I've got it now! :) Thank you again!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey A follow-up question to the "off-question" – could you refer to all kinds of leave (like sick leave, parental leave etc, as well as "vacation leave" (whatever that may be called)) as time off? Or is the construction with "off" only used for "vacation leave"?

Comment: @Mooshi It's not unusual to say that somebody is "off sick", and such time would be described as "time off sick". I think a listener would assume that "time off" without the word "sick" would be vacation leave, flexi-time or whatever. not sick leave.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you! Excellent answer :)